# How to highlight the whole log-line in color with multitail

Tags: regular-expression, colors, multitail

I'm trying to use `multitail` to tail logs with color highlights. I defined a custom color scheme in multitail.conf, something like this:

```
colorscheme:my-color
cs_re:red:^\[E
cs_re:yellow:^\[W
cs_re:magenta:^\[D
cs_re:green,,bold:All session(s) filled for.*
```

What I want to achieve with each line:

1. Color **the whole log-line** Red if it starts with string '[E'
2. Color ................................ Yellow if it starts with string '[W'
3. Color ................................ Magenta if it starts with string '[D'
4. Color ................................ Green if the line contains the string 'All session(s) filled for'

Unfortunately, none of the above is happening for me. For the first 3, it does color correctly the substring (e.g. '[E', '[W', etc) but not the whole log-line. In the last case, it doesn't color at all.

I also want to color the whole line by matching the third character of a line, e.g. color it Blue if the third character is 'A', how should I do this reliably with `multitail`?

Comment: I don't use multi-tail, but have you tried e.g.: cs_re:red:^\[E.* ?    Meh: the edit field is taking the backslash off the square bracket when I save :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use `multitail`, but looking to your regular expressions, you probably mean this:

```
colorscheme:my-color
cs_re:red:^\[E.*
cs_re:yellow:^\[W.*
cs_re:magenta:^\[D.*
cs_re:green,,bold:All session\(s\) filled for.*
```

Comment: that works. How about matching the nth character in the line?

Comment: `^.{n-1}C` where `n` is the char position and `C` is the character you want to match

Comment: explanation: `^` matches the beginning of the line, `.` matches anything except `\n`, `{n}` repeats the last expression `n` times, and `C` matches your character